# Compare each row of a data frame with all rows of another one

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

**EDIT**

The @ashkangh's answer to the original question is perfectly fine, but the question itself turned out to be a bit less trivial: for `df1` not all possible values for `width` and `thickness` but only min and max values are given. Moreover, `width` and `thickness` in both data frames are, in general, floats (not integers).

So, I have two data frames `df1` and `df2`:

```
import pandas as pd

d1 = {'order_id': range(3), 
      'width': [[0.9, 3.1], [0.7, 2.5], [1.9, 3.3]], 
      'thickness': [[9.9, 11.1], [11.7, 14.4], [9.1, 13.2]]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(d1)

df1
   order_id       width     thickness
0         0  [0.9, 3.1]   [9.9, 11.1]
1         1  [0.7, 2.5]  [11.7, 14.4]
2         2  [1.9, 3.3]   [9.1, 13.2]

d2 = {'piece_id': range(10, 15), 
      'width': [2, 3, 3, 1, 2], 
      'thickness':[10, 15, 9, 11, 12]}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(d2)

df2
   piece_id  width  thickness
0        10      2         10
1        11      3         15
2        12      3          9
3        13      1         11
4        14      2         12
```

Now I want to find what pieces from `df2` are okay for what orders in `df1`. I.e. if `df2.width` is in `df1.width` and `df2.thickness` is in `df1.thickness`.

So, the desired output should be:

```
   order_id  piece_id  width  thickness
0         0        10   True       True
1         0        11   True      False
2         0        12   True      False
3         0        13   True       True
4         0        14   True      False
5         1        10   True      False
6         1        11  False      False
7         1        12  False      False
8         1        13   True      False
9         1        14   True       True
10        2        10   True       True
11        2        11   True      False
12        2        12   True      False
13        2        13  False       True
14        2        14   True       True
```

Or, even better (only suitable `order_id`-`piece_id` pairs are kept),

```
   order_id  piece_id
0         0        10
1         0        13
2         1        14
3         2        10
4         2        14
```

I can do it with loops, but the data frames can be rather big (10^3 - 10^5 rows), so I'm wondering if there is a more smart pandas solution.

**ORIGINAL DATA FRAMES**

(`width` and `thickness` in `df1` were given explicitly and had only integers.)

```
import pandas as pd

d1 = {'order_id': range(3), 
      'width': [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2], [2, 3]], 
      'thickness': [[10, 11], [12, 13, 14], [10, 11, 12, 13]]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(d1)

df1
   order_id      width         thickness
0         0  [1, 2, 3]          [10, 11]
1         1     [1, 2]      [12, 13, 14]
2         2     [2, 3]  [10, 11, 12, 13]

d2 = {'piece_id': range(10, 15), 
      'width': [2, 3, 3, 1, 2], 
      'thickness':[10, 15, 9, 11, 12]}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(d2)

df2
   piece_id  width  thickness
0        10      2         10
1        11      3         15
2        12      3          9
3        13      1         11
4        14      2         12
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `explode` method and `merge` you can get your result:

```
df1.explode('width').explode('thickness')\
   .merge(df2, on=['width', 'thickness'], how='inner')[['order_id', 'piece_id']]
```

Output:

```
    order_id    piece_id
0     0          13
1     0          10
2     2          10
3     1          14
4     2          14
```

Comment: Your answer is totally fine, but the problem itself turned out to be a bit more tricky - I've edited the question accordingly.